# CSS transition (one way transition) based on props (styled components)

Tags: css, styled-components

I have the following styled component:

```
const S = {};

S.MentionDiv = styled.div`
  height: ${props => props.mentionOpen ? '200px' : '0px'}
  transition: height .5s ease-in-out; // THIS WORKS BOTH WAYS (OPEN AND CLOSE)
`;
```

But a need a way to have the transition to happen only from `0px` to `200px` (open action) and not the other way around. I want it to close immediately.

Can can I modify this code to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can ignore the transition when height is about changing to 0

```
const S = {};

S.MentionDiv = styled.div`
  height: ${props => props.mentionOpen ? '200px' : '0px'}
  ${props => props.mentionOpen ? 'transition: height .5s ease-in-out;': ''} `;
```